# Change target branch of open dependabot PR?

Tags: git, github, dependabot

Is it possible to change the target branch of a Pull Request that dependabot has opened?

We have set up dependabot to usually target a specific branch, that is not `main`, but for security updates it will still target main (as discussed on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67081824/is-it-possible-to-select-a-specific-branch-against-which-dependabot-should-open)). So, I would like to re-target those PRs which are targeting main directly to our normal testing branch.

Answer (score 3):

As per [Dependabot's documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#target-branch), security updates will always target the repository's *default* branch. There is no way to force Dependabot to open security-update pull requests on branches other than the default branch.

Setting the `target-branch` configuration option will cause Dependabot to ignore the entire configuration for that `package-ecosystem` when creating security-update pull requests.

A workaround would be to use a GitHub Action to switch the target branch after the pull request has been created. An example would be the [pr-target-branch-action](https://github.com/Vankka/pr-target-branch-action).

Answer (score -3):

You can use 'target-branch' config option to set the target Dependabot branch to something else than `main`: https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#target-branch

From the docs:

```yaml
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "pip"
    directory: "/"
    schedule:
      interval: "weekly"
    # Raise pull requests for version updates
    # to pip against the `develop` branch
    target-branch: "develop"
```

Comment: as I said, we are already doing that. But this is not being taken into account for security updates.